# After migrating to new site, log in broken unless cookies from old site are removed

Tags: php, linux, apache, magento, cookies

**Replication**

We have migrated a website to a new host and platform (magento). It is on a LAMP stack on Apache and Ubuntu 14.4. We have found that browsers with cookies from the old site are unable to log in after creating an account. It redirects back to login page. We find deleting the cookies from the old site allows proper log in behavior again.

We believe the browser is sending the old cookie to authenticate and is being redirect to the login page, but we'd like to confirm this and better understand the issue.

**What is the correct solution?**

Comment: If the url of the website has not changed , your browser uses the same cookie if his "name" is the same

Comment: It's kind of like when CSS gets changed and it's stuck in the browser cache. The issue is client-side and the only cure is to clear the offender out of the browser. Which unfortunately, you don't have access to.